# WordPress Clickable Title Directly Linked to URL in Post Content Like Hacker News

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

If I post a URL only in the post content in Wordpress admin, I hope readers could click the post title on homepage to visit directly the page the URL links to, other than visit the post on my Wordpress site, just like what you do on Hacker News, Reddit, or other links share sites. But if the post content is not a URL only, the Wordpress site should go as usually.

(Wordpress version 6.2.2; Theme: Hello Elementor)

The following is the codes I wrote and added in the theme's functions.php file to implement the idea above, but it failed. Please help me. Thanks.

```
function redirect_to_url_if_only_url( $post ) {
  // Check if the post content is only a URL.
  $post_content = $post->post_content;
  $url_regex = '/(http|https)://[a-zA-Z0-9\-\.]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,3}(/\S*)?/';
  if ( preg_match( $url_regex, $post_content ) ) {
    // The post content is only a URL, so redirect to the URL.
    $url = $post_content;
    wp_redirect( $url, 302 );
  }
}

add_action( 'save_post', 'redirect_to_url_if_only_url' );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using WordPress' [Post Formats](https://wordpress.org/documentation/article/post-formats/) feature will be the best way to declare that a post is a link only.

For changing the link, would be something like this (untested):

```php
add_filter( 'post_link', static function ( $permalink, $post ) {
    if ( 'link' !== get_post_format( $post ) ) {
        return $permalink;
    }

    $redirect = wp_strip_all_tags( $post->post_content );
    $redirect = esc_url_raw( $redirect, array( 'http', 'https' ) );

    if ( empty( $redirect ) ) {
        return $permalink;
    }

    return $redirect;
}, 10, 2 );
```

Comment: I created a fresh WordPress install with [the "Hello Elementor" theme](https://cln.sh/5Y812V1Y) and the above code, created a [post with the Link format and `https://www.google.com` in the post content (Gutenberg)](https://cln.sh/L4ZP8tVC), and [the link on the archive page](https://cln.sh/S7CD5yPm) worked as expected. Please elaborate on "the code doesn't work".

Comment: I didn't use "Post Format" options on Hello Elementor, so I failed. I tried again with the use of that, and your code works perfectly. Thanks again.